# Where can I store information to use across different functions

Tags: c#, scope

I know it's silly but i'm a beginner and I was asked to make a program that accepts student info from a method `GetStudentInfo()` , and use another method to print it out `PrintStudentInfo` , I got everything almost done except that I don't know where I can declare the variables. I get the name `'XXXX' doesn't exist in the current context.` , here's the code :

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        GetStudentInfo();
        printStudentInfo();

    }
    //Student info ..
    public static void GetStudentInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Student's first name : ");
        firstname = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Student's last name : ");
        lastname = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Student's Address : ");
        address = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Student's country :");
        country = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Student's state : ");
        state = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Student's Telephone number :");
        tele = Console.ReadLine();
    }
 static void printStudentInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Student name is" + firstname + lastname);
        Console.WriteLine("Prof address is " + address);
        Console.WriteLine("Student country/state is" + country + state);
        Console.WriteLine("Student telephone is " + tele);

    }
```

Comment: This isn't a scripting language.  You must declare your variables.

Comment: in this case each variable will be a string

Comment: I don't recommend it, but you can make the variable global.  This done by declaring the variables in the namespace outside of the methods.  If you did that and you are still getting the error you described, it is because the methods are static, so the variables would have to be static as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public class Student
        {
            public string firstname;
            public string lastname;
            public string address;
            public string country;
            public string state;
            public string tele;
        }
        public class StudentProcessor
        {
            //Student info ..
            public Student GetStudentInfo()
            {
                Student s = new Student();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Student's first name : ");
                s.firstname = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Enter Student's last name : ");
                s.lastname = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Enter Student's Address : ");
                s.address = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Enter Student's country :");
                s.country = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Enter Student's state : ");
                s.state = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Enter Student's Telephone number :");
                s.tele = Console.ReadLine();

                return s;
            }
            public void printStudentInfo(Student s)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Student name is" + s.firstname + s.lastname);
                Console.WriteLine("Prof address is " + s.address);
                Console.WriteLine("Student country/state is" + s.country + s.state);
                Console.WriteLine("Student telephone is " + s.tele);

            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StudentProcessor p = new StudentProcessor();
            Student s = p.GetStudentInfo();
            p.printStudentInfo(s);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: well thanks , but is there another way to do it without creating objects and run the program in the main class ?

Comment: yeah, just put all the code in the main function. and remove the 'public' from the variable declarations.

Comment: Ok , and if i want to complete the program to recieve information for professor , degree , program , and print all out should i repeat all this code sections ?

Comment: well. my suggestion is you do it, like I've suggested. but yeah you can just add more string professor = Console.ReadLine() etc

Comment: i already accepted , but i'm still learning and my goal is to know many methods and ways to solve the problem not just solving it even if it was the best answer , thanks.

Comment: sorry it was a mistake

Answer (score 1):

put:

```
private static string firstname;
private static string lastname;
private static string address;
private static string country;
private static string state;
private static string tele;
```

in the class(of the main method) body if you just want it to work, but if you want to do it better do it like Ewan said.

Eg:

```
class Program
{
    private static string firstname;
    private static string lastname;
    private static string address;
    private static string country;
    private static string state;
    private static string tele;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

     ....
    }
    ....

}
```

Comment: i tried it but it didn't work , here is the code to review it : 
http://jpst.it/yanH

Comment: See Edit: You added it into the wrong place @AhmedMohamedAshraf